# How to plot 2 to N columns of a dataframe against the first column?

Tags: r, plot

I'm an absolute beginner at R and I'm really struggling to work out how to do certain tasks. My data frame has the first column which is time ascending by 0.25 hours, then columns 2 to N are all data. I'd to plot each column against the first one in the same script.

I also am doing nonlinear regression using nlsLM on each dataset using the following code. I'm unsure how to directly plot the regression curves on the scatterplot though.

```
LMA <- nlsLM(one~SSfpl(time, lower_asymptote, upper_asymptote, halftime, rate))
summary(LMA)
```

Would it be possible to combine this all into one function? Also, how would I export the variables (lower_asymptote, upper_asymptote, halftime and rate), number of iterations and column name into a new dataframe?

Thanks so much in advance. I'm entirely out of my depth

Comment: Welcome to stack, it is easier if you provide a MWE. For example a snippet of your data and the desired outcomes. 
Start with the providing some data, the plotting functions can be looped through. You can also return each of the model element into a list/df

Comment: Also where does the nlsLM function come from? And where are you getting the variables for logistic model from?